# Error connecting to Chromium

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, dns

I got a message error on Chromium "Err_resolution_name" trying to go on https://www.google.com. The icon of wifi indicates: "No wireless interfaces found" but I'm sure my RP3 is connected to internet because when I ping to 8.8.8.8 it works.

I just don't know what's the problem. Maybe it's problem of DNS server?

Comment: what happen if you ping google.com or another URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To figure out this problem follow the instructions:

1- sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

2- change the DNS server from 127.0.0.1 to 8.8.8.8

Chromium will work then.